# Plotting number of occurrences of column value

Tags: python, pandas

I hope the title is accurate enough, I wasn't quite sure how to phrase it.

Anyhow, my problem is that I have a Pandas df which looks like the following:

```
                              Customer       Source  CustomerSource
0                                Apple            A             141
1                                Apple            B              36
2                            Microsoft            A             143
3                               Oracle            C             225
4                                  Sun            C             151
```

This is a df derived from a greater dataset, and the meaning the value of `CustomerSource` is that it's the accumulated sum of all occurrences of `Customer` and `Source`, for example, in this case there is 141 occurrences of `Apple` with `Soure` `A` and 225 of `Customer` `Oracle` with `Source` `B` and so on.

What I want to do with this, is I want to do a stacked barplot which gives me all `Customer`s on the x-axis and the values of `CustomerSource` stacked on top of each other on the y-axis. Similar to the below example. Any hints as to how I would proceed with this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) or [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshape and then [`DataFrame.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
df.pivot('Customer','Source','CustomerSource').plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

---

```
df.set_index(['Customer','Source'])['CustomerSource'].unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Or if duplicates in pairs `Customer`, `Source` use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) or `groupby` with aggregate `sum`:

```
print (df)
    Customer Source  CustomerSource
0      Apple      A             141 <-same Apple, A
1      Apple      A             200 <-same Apple, A
2      Apple      B              36
3  Microsoft      A             143
4     Oracle      C             225
5        Sun      C             151

df = df.pivot_table(index='Customer',columns='Source',values='CustomerSource', aggfunc='sum')
print (df)
Source         A     B      C
Customer                     
Apple      341.0  36.0    NaN <-141 + 200 = 341
Microsoft  143.0   NaN    NaN
Oracle       NaN   NaN  225.0
Sun          NaN   NaN  151.0


df.pivot_table(index='Customer',columns='Source',values='CustomerSource', aggfunc='sum')
  .plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

---

```
df.groupby(['Customer','Source'])['CustomerSource'].sum().unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Also is possible swap columns:

```
df.pivot('Customer','Source','CustomerSource').plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image: g]

```
df.pivot('Source', 'Customer','CustomerSource').plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image: g1]